# Is it incorrect to calculate residuals directly from a phylogenetically-controlled linear regression?

Tags: regression, residuals, phylogeny

I would like to calculate the residuals from a regression of log body mass and log brain mass, controlling for phylogeny. I originally used phylolm in R to run this regression, under a Brownian Motion assumption. I then saw that there is a function (phyl.resid) in phytools that is designed to calculate this, so I used that (again, set under the Brownian Motion assumption). I compared the two methods and the results are very different (I've double-checked that they are both using the same data and tree). Is the first method wrong? I also ran a non-phylogenetic regression and the pattern of residuals from that is almost identical to that given by phyl.resid. Can anyone explain why phylolm might be giving such a different result? I'm not sure which method I should be using.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation to see what the two functions do exactly?

Comment: Yes - as far as I can tell, they're doing the same thing, but clearly they are not and I am not knowledgeable enough to understand what's causing the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that residuals from a phytools::phyl.resid are identical to a normal lm is not surprising - phytools::phyl.resid seems to call nlme::gls, which is fitting a standard GLS. Such a model is accounting for the residuals correlation in the likelihood (thus re-weighting data points and correcting p-values / CIs), but the correlated residuals are not actively estimated and thus it is not possible to condition on them. In other words: your model predictions, and thus also your residuals, are calculated based on fixed effect structure only, which is likely very similar to that of a model with iid assumptions.

I am not sure if phylolm has a different approach, and does allow to condition on the correlated residuals. In principle, this is possible, it just depends on the implementation of the model. This [recent MEE paper](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.13971) discusses this at length.